# SharePoint Server Object model (SPSite & SPWeb)

Tags: c#, javascript, sharepoint-2010, ssis

I'm using VS 2010 on Windows XP. I did download microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll & microsoft.sharepoint.client.Runtime.dll from Microsoft Client Object model on my computer.

I was able to find above dll's in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\SharePoint Client, Not at below location. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI -- as pointed on some other articles and stackoverflow question.

Task: SSIS & SharePoint Integration and download files from SharePoint site (SP 2010).

Here is the problem. I'm trying to use namespace SPSite and SPWebsite but VS 2010 doesn't recognize. I have add above mentioned dlls as reference and my target framework 4.0.

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl)) --Error: The type or namespace SpSite couldn't be found (are you missing using directive or assembly reference).

Looks like i need to install something on Sharepoint Server as Server Object Model.
1. Could you tell me what i need to install on Sharepoint Server.
2. After #1, what do i need to do in C# program so that i can access those Server side object.

Please advice steps in details as i'm a newbie to .Net.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing 2 different technologies: Server Object Model and Client Object Model.

The code snippet you posted is Sharepoint Object model and you can only compile/run it on a SharePoint server, but the libraries you referenced are CLient Object Model.

If you want to access Sharepoint functionality remotely (as it appears you do)  you need to use Client Object Model.

A sample code using Client Object Model that retrieves all the items from a task list:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://mySharepointSite.com");
List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = "<View/>";
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

context.Load(list);
context.Load(items);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Check here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-Introduction

Comment: Thanks for your response Luis. I'm able to get items that exists on sharepoint site but my problem/task is to download files in the document library folder to local folder. There could be 10 or more files such as *.cvs or *.xls. 1. Do you, above works for document library files too or do i need to do anything different. 2. Even the  reference link you sent me talks about items on Sharepoint site not document library files and i need to download files from SP site. Please let me know the above code works for downloading files or it's just items of SP site.